# new-compliancesearcaction delete more than 10 mails

Tags: office365

By negligence or mistake from my colleague we need to delete all mails before a specific date. When we do a content search it comes to 5 million emails(many items per mailbox, way more than 10)

Is there another way to delete those emails? We used a search-mailbox but that is too slow.

Comment: What mistake you did ?

Comment: I believe that they tried to bomb someone? ;)